# XML RPC non-object on scalarval

Tags: php, odoo, xml-rpc

I have the following script to login to openERP:

```
<?php
include('../xmlrpc/lib/xmlrpc.inc');

$dbname = 'km';
$user = 'admin';
$pwd = 'pass';
$url = 'http://localhost:8069'; // it's demo server url
$sock = new xmlrpc_client("http://localhost:8069");

$sock_msg = new xmlrpcmsg('login');
$sock_msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($dbname, "string"));
$sock_msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($user, "string"));
$sock_msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($pwd, "string"));
$sock_resp = $sock->send($sock_msg);

if ($sock_resp->errno != 0){
echo  'error';
}else{

$sock_val = $sock_resp->value();

$user_id = $sock_val->scalarval();

}
?>
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function scalarval() on a non-object in (whatever)
```

I don't know where i am failing here. Is it something in the configuration? or perhaps i am doing something else wrong.

Since i am new to XMLRPC and OpenERP, please provide as much information as possible.

Thanks !

Comment: First check if $sock_val is actually object (maybe it is null). After that, you can check if your $sock_val->scalarval() is actually scalar by calling this line of code: if($val->kindOf()=="scalar"). Only if this is true, then you can call your scalarval() on your $sock_val object.

Comment: please append the output of `print_r($sock_val);`.

Comment: tried to `print_r($sock_val);` and it's value is 0.

Comment: Still no more respondes.. Please help

Comment: facing the same error. armandomaria, you got a solution for this?